# Android studio ERRO java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, notifyicon

Estou desenvolvendo um código no android studio e utilizando comunicação bluetooth. Quero fazer com que se um dado especifico recebido pelo bluetooth seja maior que tal valor, automaticamente gere uma notificação no celular.

O erro:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>
> 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
>
> on a null object reference

Código:

```
public static Handler handler = new Handler() {
@Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        /* Esse método é invocado na Activity principal
            sempre que a thread de conexão Bluetooth recebe
            uma mensagem.
         */

        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
        byte[] data = bundle.getByteArray("data");

        String dataString= new String(data);
        String sep[] = dataString.split(Pattern.quote("E"));

        /* Aqui ocorre a decisão de ação, baseada na string
            recebida. Caso a string corresponda à uma das
            mensagens de status de conexão (iniciadas com --),
            atualizamos o status da conexão conforme o código.
         */

        if(dataString.equals("---N"))
            statusMessage.setText("Erro de conexão.");
        else if(dataString.equals("---S"))
            statusMessage.setText("Conectado.");
        else{
            funciona2 = Integer.parseInt(sep[1]);

            ActDados actDados = new ActDados();
            actDados.notifica();

        }

    }

};
```

Função `notifica`:

```
public void notifica(){

    NotificationManager nm = 
  (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, 
ActTelaUsuarios1.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new 
    NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    builder.setTicker("Ticker Texto")
            .setContentTitle("Atenção")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

    if (funciona2 > 60 && funciona2 < 120){
        builder.setContentText("Texto notificado 1");
    }
    else{
    builder.setContentText("Texto notificado 2");
    }

    builder.setContentIntent(p);

    Notification n = builder.build();
    n.vibrate = new long[]{150, 300, 150, 600};
    nm.notify(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, n);
```

}

Compilo o código e passo ele para o celular, porém quando está rodando o aplicativo ele aviso que houve erro e trava o app.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>
> 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
>
> on a null object reference
>   at com.example.vitor.teste.ActDados.notifica(ActDados.java:206)
>   at com.example.vitor.teste.ActDados$1.handleMessage(ActDados.java:288)

O erro informa a linha onde chamo a função de notificação : `actDados.notifica();`

Comment: O que está na linha 206 do ficheiro ActDados.java ?

Comment: O problema me parece estar ao executar `n.vibrate = new long[]{150, 300, 150, 600};`. O que você está fazendo nessa linha?